# JQuery: accordion heightStyle: fill causing vertical scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just recently added the JQuery accordion affect to my site and applied the heightStyle: fill so that it would fill up the entire window.

However, it's filling up what looks like an extra 1px or maybe 2px, and now it's causing the vertical scroll bar to appear.  I'm thinking I have extra padding that may be causing it, or some margin somewhere, but I've tried everything and can't seem to figure out where the extra pixel or two are coming from.

**Can you guys figure out where?**  I just want to get rid of it so that it fills the entire page, but doesn't cause the vertical scrollbar.

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/r2Vra/  (If you resize the result window you will need to re-run)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div id="palette">
        <div id="accordion">
          <h3>Upper Case</h3>
          <div id="upperCase"></div>
          <h3>Lower Case</h3>
          <div id="lowerCase"></div>
          <h3>Numbers</h3>
          <div id="numbers"></div>
          <h3>Punctuation</h3>
          <div id="punctuation"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="canvas">
        <div id="trash"><a href="#"></a></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
/****************************************************************************************
* GENERAL
*****************************************************************************************/

html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

/****************************************************************************************
* PALETTE
*****************************************************************************************/

#palette {
float: left;
width: 320px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #888;
padding: 0 5px;
background: url(../img/texture.png) repeat;
}

#palette .letter {
    font-family: 'Chango', cursive;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    cursor: move;
}


/****************************************************************************************
* CANVAS
*****************************************************************************************/

#canvas {
margin-left: 320px;
height: 100%;
z-index: 0;

background: url(../img/refrigerator.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-position: left 200px center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 
}

#canvas .newLetter {
    font-family: 'Chango', cursive;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 4.4em;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    cursor: move;
}

#trash {
position:fixed;
right:0;
bottom:10px;
z-index: 100;
}

#trash a{
display: block;
background: url(../img/trashcan-sprite-tiny2.png) no-repeat;
height: 110px;
width: 125px;
}

#trash a:hover{
background-position: 0px -113px;
}

#trash img {
border: none;
}

/****************************************************************************************
* JQUERY UI CSS OVERRIDE
*****************************************************************************************/

#accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    padding: 0 .5em;
}

/*
.ui-helper-reset {
line-height: 1.2;
}

.ui-widget {
font-size: 1em;
} */
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "fill" });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that works for me.

I just added an extra div and made it's boundaries a bit smaller than the parent div.

**NOTE:** It's unfortunate that I had to add an extra div, so if anyone still knows an alternative then let me know.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="palette">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="accordion">
              <h3>Upper Case</h3>
              <div id="upperCase"></div>
              <h3>Lower Case</h3>
              <div id="lowerCase"></div>
              <h3>Numbers</h3>
              <div id="numbers"></div>
              <h3>Punctuation</h3>
              <div id="punctuation"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    height: 99.5%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding this:

```
#accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

It's not perfect solution but it works.

Comment: Hmm, try `margin-bottom: -4px` then click on the last header in the accordion.  The div underneath the header fills the page with those extra 2px still.  You'll notice that it jumps.  Something makes me think it's the accordion body elements that are filling incorrectly.